# Why am I getting a connection timeout error with ssh?

Tags: windows, ssh, timeout

First of all, I'm pretty new to SSH. I've used it before, but never had to deal much with setting it up or navigating the details. Migrated from ServerFault.

Whenever I try to ssh to a public ip address from my windows 10 computer, I get an error that looks like `ssh: connect to username@<public ip address> port 22: Connection timed out`.

I can connect to my own linux machine from windows with a private ip address, and my windows machine connects to github with ssh public/private key authentication. My linux machine can connect to external servers (like AWS) via ssh, it's just my windows machine, and just public IP addresses, so far as I can tell.

Here's the output with the `-vv` option, and on a different port:

```
ssh -vv -p 2200 example.com                                                                                  OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5                                                                                       debug2: resolving "example.com" port 2200                                                                                       debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0                                                                                          debug1: Connecting to example.com [93.184.216.34] port 2200.                                                                    debug1: connect to address 93.184.216.34 port 2200: Connection timed out                                                        ssh: connect to host example.com port 2200: Connection timed out
```

**What is causing this problem, and what do I need to do to fix it, so that I can ssh to external servers from my windows 10 computer?**

I can ping external servers fine:

```
Pinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=54 
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=54
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=54
Reply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=54
      
Ping statistics for 1.1.1.1:
packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),                                                                Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:                                                                              Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 74ms, Average = 36ms
```

Comment: I think port 22 is not open on the ssh server. Contact the server administrator. If it is a windows server then ask to port forward 22 on ICF. Or if it is a linux server then do `sudo ufw allow 22`.

Comment: The ssh server you are attempting to connect to will have sshd running on one port and that need not be `22`. Many servers move ssh to a high port to cut down on the number of unauthorized login attempts they receive. Can you connect to that same site on port 22 from your Linux box? A timeout means either the remote ssh server isn't running -or- it is running on a different port. You can add `-vv` as the option to increase the amount of debug info you get on the connection

Comment: I am able to connect to the server (like AWS) with a linux desktop, though- doesn't that mean that the port is open? Perhaps this is a different question, but I'm trying to connect to that linux desktop as a sort of testbed (private works fine on that), so what should I do to make it publicly accessible, and secure?

Comment: @JW0914 could you please explain the edits that you made? Why the information in the question was irrelevant?

Comment: I rolled back the edit as it removed a lot relevant info (I'm on a cell so I can't edit it easily). That said, there are edits that would be appropriate to cut down statements not relevant to the problem and better format the post.

Comment: @fyzx92 First paragraph is a salutation and questions/answers shouldn't have salutations per the site. Third paragraph has nothing to do with the IP you're attempting to SSH to and is therefore irrelevant. All SSH output belongs in one code box, not three, and once done, the bulk of the content of paragraphs two, four, and seven becomes redundant and unnecessary. As to the `ping` content, showing it is irrelevant, as all that needs to be said is the ping reply took `x` amount of seconds. Once done, what's left is paragraphs two and five, with two containing the applicable SSH output.

Comment: @davidgo What do you believe is relevant that was removed _(please see my above comment and offer insight)_?

Comment: @jw0914 I agree the question was wordy, and the first paragraph maybe unnecessary (but it was not a salutation and useful helping with level to answer at). Gutting and moving para 2 and 3 lost a lot of detail important to the question, ie advising what did and did not work. In replacing question paragraph 5 you again removed clues to the problem and also changed what was being sought. Removing ping output removed evidence the problem was not routing related. Likewise removing SSH output when trying to connect to port 2200 his the opportunity to explain the faulty in the logic used...

Comment: @jw0914 the bottom line though was that when I read it the question (as you edited it) made little sense to me. What was being asked was immediately apparent when I looked at the original.  Also, bear in mind the idea is to provide answers findable by people searching (possibly on the incorrect track) in Google, and removing info that you and I know to be extraneous may make it harder for people who don't know what they don't know to get good information.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of reasons this could be happening - these are likely due to firewalling going on somewhere.

SSH sits on top of TCP. When you get connection timed out errors it means that the problem is that the SSH client is not seeing any responses from the server (ie the TCP handshake is not completing) which almost always means the problems is not with SSH, rather its at a lower level.  This also explains why you get this error on ports that SSH is not listening on.

The first thing I do is examine firewall rules to check they are allowing SSH through. As the problem seems limited to your laptop/desktop, checking the local firewall and AV software is a good place to start.

If that does not solve it, break out traffic sniffers - seeing if the server receives and sends traffic  is a useful hint. As its Linux, running something like

```
  tcpdump -n -i any src or dst XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Can be useful where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is your external IP and where your monitoring us taking place from a computer not on the same man as your desktop.(maybe SSH to an intermediate server ie using a cellular connection or vpn?)

If its a complex network you may need to get your network administrator involved. If its a simple network where you are the network admin you might want to suspect an issue with port forwarding on your router and/or bad config related to this.

Using a VPN can "virtually move" the apparent point if your connection and can be useful for diagnosing/bypassing firewall issues.

Comment: To check the firewall, what exactly should I be looking for? I've got windows defender open, but don't see a clear outbound rule or app permission entry related to ssh. Plenty related to networking and shells, but nothing really stands out to me.