Copying file from my computer to AlmaLinux on virtual box
I want to copy file from my local computer to AlmaLinux installed on virtual box I used this command scp /home/odaiz/odaiz.txt 192.168.100.2:C:\Users\odaya\Desktop\share but I got this error from ssh:
connect to host 192.168.100.2 port 22: Connection timed out
Connection closed


Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1567769/62676
